# MVC bin folder, why are there so many dll files

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have more than 50 dll files in the bin folder in my mvc project. As someone who has just switched from web forms to mvc, why are there so many dll files. Only 2 files belong to me, K20.DAL and K20.BLL files. Are there any IIS configurations so as not to upload other DLL files to the server for each project?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the other DLLs are present because they are referenced by your K20.DAL and K20.BLL project references. Few DLLs are part of MVC framework. When ever your application is running, only the DLL which is needed by your code currently executing will be loaded into AppDomain memory. This is on-demand-loading. After the code execution is over, the DLL will be unloaded from the memory. If some DLL which is needed by your code, but if it is not present, then your code breaks.  There may be some shared DLLs also used by your application which will there in .net GAC assembly folder but not in bin folder.
So there is no harm to deploy these DLLs to server if you are not sure whether your application is using them or not.
Hope this clarifies your doubt.